# XPages onComplete event and visibility in the UI

Tags: xpages

Why can't I see the onComplete event in my 8.5.3 Designer client for any control? I had to manually type in this.onComplete? A screenshot of where it's meant to appear would be really appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't show that easy, I don't know why IBM has hidden it.
You can find it. if you have an object that has some other event specified.
in the outline window, there will be a event handler click on this.
Then in the properties panel you will se the oncomplete. Easy no.[image: oncomplete]

Comment: No it doesn't only in the properties panel

Comment: Well correct me if im wrong but in the case of a button onClick event, the onClick is an event on the button that gets executed, but the onComplete doesn't get executed on the button its self its merely an action for the onClick event. There isn't anything on the button thats getting "completed" its to do with the partail refresh coming from the onClick. In that case it makes sense its not an event on the button in the events tab because its used on top of other events

Comment: Thanks Fredrik and Simon, much appreciated. I agree with Simon, but it has to be intituative for the developers and new comers. At the moment it isn't!

Comment: onComplete is a client side event executed when the serverside onClick is done. I use the onComplete event on buttons to handle when I want to do multiple refreshes. Because we can't do that out of the box.